# C# how can I do something if I press a key only one time

Tags: c#

```
while true
{
 if (checkBox1.Checked & KKEY == "CapsLock")
  {
    if (sim.InputDeviceState.IsKeyDown(VirtualKeyCode.CAPITAL))
       {
        (Send something)
        Thread.Sleep(100);
       }
   }
 }
```

I want to know how can I send something only one time in this code.

I tried to delay the sends with `thread.sleep` because when I press the key it sends multiple times but I want only to send something 1 time per key click.

I tried to break but that cut the if and it only send the key one time and then never send it again.

Is there any way to do what I want to do? Thanks!

Edit: I forgot to put the while sorry.
Holding the key should be one click and when is pressed again i need the send something again.

Comment: Define what you exactly mean with click in "1 time per click". if holding the key should be one click until key is released then detect if a keyup has happened in the meantime.

Comment: Yes sorry. Holding the key should be one click and when is pressed again i need the send something again.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your question correctly, a solution somewhat like this should work:

```
bool keyPressed = false;
if (checkBox1.Checked & KKEY == "CapsLock")
{
    if (sim.InputDeviceState.IsKeyDown(VirtualKeyCode.CAPITAL) && !keyPressed)
    {
        keyPressed = true;
        (Send something)
                    
    }
    if (sim.InputDeviceState.IsKeyUp(VirtualKeyCode.CAPITAL))
    {
        keyPressed = false;            
    }
}
```

I am not that familiar with "sim" but you can modify the code as needed.

Comment: Im so sorry i forgot to put the while. I tried but the program still doing the same.